# Site Import Error

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, web-part, 2016, error

I am currently getting the error below when importing a site and I have no idea what is causing it, can anyone help?

> [FatalError][-2146231999][System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidationException][The element 'View' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema' has invalid child element 'ParameterBinding' in namespace 'urn:deployment-manifest-schema'. List of possible elements expected: 'Script, PagedRowset, PagedClientCallbackRowset, PagedReccuranceRowset, ViewFields, ViewData, List, MetaData, View, Query, RowLimit, RowLimitExceeded, Mobile, MobileItemLimit, Toolbar, Formats, Aggregations, ViewStyle, Viewbody, ViewEmpty, ViewFooter, ViewHeader,  ViewBidiHeader, GroupByFooter, GroupByHeader, CalendarViewStyles, CalendarSettings, ListFomBody, Xsl, XslLink, JS, JSLink, ParameterBindings, OpenApplicationExtension, Method, WebParts,  InlineEdit, Joins, ProjectedFields' in namespace 'urn:deplyment-manifest-schema'.]

Comment: As per [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/view-element-list), child element should be 'ParameterBindings' (with "s" at the end) and not 'ParameterBinding'. Try this and let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this documentation - [View element (List)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/view-element-list),

Child element inside `<View>` element should be **ParameterBindings** (with "s" at the end) and not "ParameterBinding".

Change your view element XML according and it should work for you.

**Documentation**: [View element (List) - Child elements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/schema/view-element-list#child-elements)

---

**Example**:

```
<View>
    <ParameterBindings>
        <ParameterBinding Name = "Text" Location = "Text" />
        <ParameterBinding Name = "Text" Location = "Text" />
        <ParameterBinding Name = "Text" Location = "Text" />
    </ParameterBindings>
</View>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, where would I be able to find the ViewElementXML on the site/in the .cmp  backup file? @Ganesh

Comment: Check this article for more information: https://techtrainingnotes.blogspot.com/2007/12/exploring-sharepoint-cmp-backup-files.html

Comment: Thanks!  I have been able to find the files within the  .cmp file now, I can see various ParameterBindings and ParameterBinding entries throughout the Minifest.xml, is this the correct place  to be searching for malformed xml, if so, how can I re-package the .cmp file? @Ganesh

Comment: You will find these entries in Manifest.xml and ViewFormsList.xml file. To re-package, try [this](https://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2010/01/editing-cmp-files-to-fix-lookup-field.html) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1378997/how-to-re-compress-the-cmp-file-created-by-stsadm-export-command-after-editin)

Comment: Nice yes, I was able to successfully import using the -nofilecompression flag, one last question if you don't mind, do you know how this could be caused in the first place, seems to happen when there's only 1 <ParameterBinding> the <ParameterBindings> gets missed, what could trigger this? I will mark as Resolved thanks so much ! @Ganesh

Comment: Sorry, I am not completely sure why this caused in the first place. Maybe there is a bug in system which does not add `<ParameterBindings>` when there is only one `<ParameterBinding>`.